# Magento localhost migration index.php and admin issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, admin

On the server, my website uses `mod-rewrite` to structure urls without `index.php` but after I downloaded the website to my local machine, none of the links work without `index.php`. I'm using the same files, the same `.htaccess` and I'm using the same domain in localhost.

Other issue is that the admin login just shows a blank page, no errors. I've enabled errors using this in `index.php`, and enabled it in `php.ini`:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: Uh...um,.....what?

Comment: i downloaded my magento site, but it have many issues in urls. in server the urls works like '/product-name...' but in localhost it show me an NOT FOUND error. So if i modify manualy url like 'index.php/product-name...' it works

Comment: check if you have all the files properly downloaded. Like the css and db

Comment: Is the apache rewrite module enabled? 
did you checked apache error logs, magento system & exception logs?

Comment: Yes, the problem was , i had AllowOverride Deny All in my main httpd.

Comment: But, my admin url doesnt work. keep redirecting to https

Comment: Cleaning up the language to make the problem more apparent.

Answer (score 0):

On localhost may be url rewrite engine is off or either not working. 
If you don't want index.php in url then you can remove that
just go to `System > Configuration > General Tab > Web > Search Engines Optimization > Make it YES`
For adding index.php in url make Search Engines Optimization = NO
And for admin if you are using linux then check permissions of the folder.
Check console for errors in inspect element.